# How to compute the following double integral: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\arctan\left(x\right)}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln\left|\cos\left(y\right)\right|dydx$

Tags: integration

How to compute the following double integral: $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\arctan\left(x\right)}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln\left|\cos\left(y\right)\right|dydx$$

I'm new to double integrals and order chaning, as I know in this example $\int_{\arctan\left(x\right)}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln\left|\cos\left(y\right)\right|dy$ is not easy to compute and it's better to change the order of integration, though I don't know how to do that, moreover does there exist any software of website that I can use to change the order of integration?

Comment: This integral can be rewritten as $\int ^{\frac{\pi }{4}}_{0}\int ^{\tan y}_{0}\ln\cos ydxdy$. Can you proceed now?

Comment: To change the order, draw a diagram representing the area under which the integral is calculated. Then, get x as a function of y, and find the limits of y (as the order is being changed from y to x, else you would have to do the reverse)

Comment: @masaheb changing the order around is allowed thanks to Fubini's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The integral can be rewritten as
$\int ^{\frac{\pi }{4}}_{0}\int ^{\tan y}_{0}\ln\cos ydxdy$.

Integrating wrt x, it evaluates to $\int ^{\frac{\pi }{4}}_{0}\tan y\cdotp \ln\cos ydy$ as
$\ln \left| \cos y\right| =\ln\cos y$  for $ y\in \left( 0,\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$.

To evaluate the above integral, substitute $\ln\cos y=t,\ \tan y\,dy=dt$.